# Log-scale transformation of histogram and fittiting gamma curve

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bunch of data, that I've fitted with a gamma distribution. I've got the histogram and the fitting curve just fine, but now I wish to draw a histogram and the curve with x in log scale. Using scale_x_log10 works just fine for the histogram, but I can't make it work for the stat_function/geom_line.

I understand that's because stat_function now takes the log values, but I'm not sure how to transform the gamma function beforehand for it to work properly. Here are the relevant pictures and code snippets:

This is the original graph:

```
fit.gamma2 <- fitdist(myvalues[,1],distr="gamma",method="mme")

ggplot(myvalues, aes(x = V1)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y =..density..),
                 boundary = 0,
                 binwidth = sirina,
                 col="black",
                 fill="blue",
                 alpha=.2) +
  stat_function(fun=dgamma,
                args=list(shape = fit.gamma2$estimate["shape"],
                          rate = fit.gamma2$estimate["rate"])) +
  labs(title="Histogram žarkov + Gama porazdelitev (MM)",
       x = "Medprihodni časi (s)",
       y = "Gostota")
```

[image: Histogram with fitted gamma curve]

This is that same graph after using scale_x_log10. The red curve is supposed to be the fitting curve, but it's obviously way off.

```
ggplot(myvalues, aes(x = V1)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y =..density..),
                 boundary = 0,
                 binwidth = sirina_log,
                 col="black",
                 fill="blue",
                 alpha=.2) + 
  stat_function(fun=dgamma,
                args=list(shape = fit.gamma2$estimate["shape"],
                          rate = fit.gamma2$estimate["rate"])) +
  # geom_line(aes(x=V1,y=dgamma(V1,fit.gamma2$estimate["shape"], fit.gamma2$estimate["rate"])), color="red", size = 1) +
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image: Log scaled graph]

I have tried applying the values in 10**x form, but as my original data ranges between 0.1 and 800, some values then escape to Inf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform your PDF based on the derivative of `log10`. First create a function for the transformed PDF:

```
dgammalog10 <- function(x, shape, rate) {
  return(x*log(10)*dgamma(x, shape, rate))
}
```

Then you can use `fun=dgammalog10` where you had `fun=dgamma`.

Comment: Oh, of course, I'm an idiot. I did make a separate function, but instead of multiplying by log(10) I was doing 10 to the power of the whole time. Thank you very much.